# Retain value of checkbox when refreshed

Tags: jquery, jsp, cookies

My problem is that when I try to check a checkbox and refresh the page, the checkbox returns to being uncheck.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src ="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input.box").each(function() {
          var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
          if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
          $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
            }
            });
        $("input.box").change(function() {
            $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
     });
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%" height="60%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" height="20%"><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="1" /></td>
            <td width="20%" height="20%"><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="2" /></td>
            <td width="20%" height="20%"><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="3" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

What do you think is the problem with the code? suggestion please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the script in `document.ready`, inorder to your jquery work and store and retrieve the `cookies`, as the jquery code runs before the required html elements are being added to `DOM`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.box").each(function() {
          var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
          if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
          $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
            }
            });
        $("input.box").change(function() {
            $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: Cannot accept as answer for now. But, now it works. Thank you.